# How to dynamicaly change title in my google chart when it animated?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

To change values of my bars I am using:

```
data.setValue(0, 1, 1);
data.setValue(1, 1, 2);
data.setValue(2, 1, 9);
```

But how can I change my titles? When I am creating new data object, animation becomes broken, so I need the fluent method to change titles dynamicaly....
Full code: https://jsfiddle.net/u0q8sk6t/5/

Answer (score 0):

Discovering data object properties I found some hack. I just change data object before animation:

```
data.hc[0][0].wf = "Lorem";
data.hc[1][0].wf = "Ipsum";
data.hc[2][0].wf = "Dolor";
```

Comment: try --> `data.setColumnLabel(colIndex, "Lorem");`